# Replacing fragments dynamically not on button click or orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am reading data from a microcontroller from usb serial port.

Based on the data i receive i want to replace the fragments.

When i try my below code on button click the fragment gets replaced perfectly. But when i try to replace the fragment under some other conditions like is strings matched then it is not working.

It is not giving any error also. It just restarts the application.

I am using two fragmets firstscreen and RinseFragment.

On activity start firstscreen fragment is added . on string matched RinseFragment should replace firstscreen fragment.

Please refer my code below.

```
public class ProcessActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public Physicaloid phy;
TextView status;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_process);



    phy = new Physicaloid(this);

    openDevice();


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);

    FirstScreen fs = new FirstScreen();
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fs).commit();

}

 private void openDevice() {
        if (!phy.isOpened()) {
            if (phy.open()) { // default 9600bps
                    phy.addReadListener(new ReadLisener() {
                    String readStr;
                    @Override
                    public void onRead(int size) {
                        byte[] buf = new byte[size];

                        phy.read(buf, size);
                        try {
                            readStr = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
                           modeselector(readStr);
                           finish();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    } 

 public void modeselector(String s){

     if(s.equals("R_A")){

         RinseFragment rFragment = new RinseFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                       transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, rFragment);
                       transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                       transaction.commit();
     }
     if(s.equals("R_S")){

         tvAppend(status,"RINSING . . .");

     }

     else
     {

     }

 }

 BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                closeDevice();
            }
        }
    };

    private void closeDevice() {
        if(phy.close()) {
          phy.clearReadListener();         
        }
    }
```

Now my main activity xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".ProcessActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#10000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rinse"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="RINSE" 
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        android:background="#53CF29"
        android:onClick="onrinse"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dprep"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="PREPARATION" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialysis"
         android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="DIALYSIS" 
         android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disinfect"
         android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="DISINFECT"
         android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        />

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/statusbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#30000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="STATUS : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CALIBRATION FINISHED"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now my fragment files both are same with no contents , empty xml files.

FirstScreen.java

```
public class FirstScreen extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstscreen, container,false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Hey sorry folks i made a silly mistake. I was calling finish() after replacing the fragment . So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

modify the try-catch block inside the openDevice() method to get the error log

```
 try {
       //your code
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

this will print the error log and then you can identify the exact problem. and then it will easy to the stackoverflow people to answer your question when you publish the error log.

Comment: reading from the device is not an issue , It is reading correct data. This i am sure of . I checked it by opening up a new activity rather than replacing fragment. It worked. Also my issue is that i cant debug and run simultaneously. I am connecting my tablet to the microcontroller through otg to usb cable .

Comment: I further saw that it is replacing the fragment and then it is getting closed with no error. My fragment xml is a blank one containing only one relative layout.